# GetX page routing returns "Null check operator used on a null value" error

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx, null-safety

I am trying to do a very simple page routing with GetX using the latest version of Flutter which includes null safety. It keeps returning the error "Null check operator used on a null value" even when I am passing no arguments or referencing any variables.

Here is my very simple code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      getPages: [GetPage(name: PageTwo.id, page: () => PageTwo())],
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _newPage() {
    Get.toNamed(PageTwo.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _newPage,
        tooltip: 'newPage',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PageTwo extends StatelessWidget {
  static String id = 'page2';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text('hi'),
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, no reason to pick up any null values.

I am using the following packages in my pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  get: ^4.3.4
```

Comment: what line #?  should ie in error msg--post the whole msg pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using named routes in Flutter, its best to always use a `/` before the name. So for you it would be

```
 static const id = '/page2'; // const not part of the fix, but it can and should be const
```

This will get rid of the null error.

You can also navigate without named routes and that error won't be an issue either.

```
Get.to(() => PageTwo());
```